# How should i select motor and blades for my Hexacopter?

Tags: quadcopter, battery, brushless-motor, flight-controller

I'm designing a fluid sprayer Drone **(HEXACOPTER)** for Agriculture as my college final year project. The capacity of the fluid spraying unit including fluid & Sprayer around 2kg. I don't know how to select motor and blades. Can you suggest to me what motor and blade can be used for my project? within 30k. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics:SE. What has your research shown you so far? You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: what does 30k mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motor and blades must be selected on the basis of amount of thrust required. Estimation of thrust of a motor depends on battery voltage, prop size and motor choice. Changing one of these will change the amount of thrust generated.

Motors must be purchased from the manufacturers providing thrust tables that shows how many grams of thrust will be generated for different variables mentioned above.

Let us assume that there is a thrust value of 670 grams for a 1045 prop at 11.1 volts  and 490 grams for a 8045 props at 11.1 volts according to the thrust table of a specific motor. Further the required thrust to weight ratio for the aircraft to fly is 2:1 then, the total thrust produced by 8045 props will be 490×6=2940 grams and that by 1045 props will be 670×6=4020 grams. 
Assuming the total weight of the aircraft to be 1.5 kilograms, a total thrust of 2940 would be pretty close to what is required for the craft to fly.

This is just an example to help understand the concept behind. You can adopt this approach to choose correct parts for the specifications provided by you.
Coming to the cost part which you want to be <=30k rupees is something no one can assure because the cost of the parts will differ from manufacturer to manufacturer and there might be other factors involved into it like customs. So, you will have to compare the prices on your own or you can check with various forums to get used parts for a cheaper price for overall cost reduction.

Hope this helped ;)
Happy flying!!

Comment: Can I use 3 blades instead of 2 blades with the same pitch and dia to increase the thrust of my motor? Will it burn my motor? or it will damage my ESC?